# Please explain SQL Azure "master" database

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, cloud, azure-sql-database

What's the "master" database in SQL Azure for? I just created a subscription and once I created a "new SQL Server" I immediately got "master" database with 1GB size. That database can't be deleted - "delete" button is not active in the management portal.

When I tried to deploy a .dbproj project there Visual Studio said it "couldn't deploy to a system database".

Can I use that database for storing my data? Do I create a new database instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`master` is a required system database that's responsible for holding info about all the the other database on the server instance, system metrics/config, managing logins & database creation etc, its read-only and can't be removed.

You will need to create a new database and deploy to that.

Comment: @Alex that is incorrect. This master isn't exactly equivalent to the sql server 'master'. That is not exposed to the user. This doesn't contain any information about the sql server instance running on that node. Although, it does contain meta-data like you said..logins,usage-views etc belonging to the particular user. In the cluster it's stored like any other partition and is replicated. @OP this is completely free. There are views in it that you can query and look at your billing and usage information.

Answer (score 11):

Just a note: you will not be charged for the master DB.

Comment: A very useful note I might add. I was just getting riled up on this 'forced 1gb database' when I read your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Exactly what I was searching :)

Comment: I ended up writing a blog post about it. Check it out: http://parasdoshi.com/2012/04/29/whats-the-role-of-a-master-database-in-a-sql-azure-world/

Comment: Any references to a microsoft website on this? :-)

Answer (score 3):

The master database records all the system-level information for a SQL Server system. This includes instance-wide metadata such as logon accounts, endpoints, linked servers, and system configuration settings