# Azure SQL Server Can't create table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

A couple of weeks ago, I acquired a SQL Server database and started to develop my application with it with no problems since then.

Today, out of nowhere, I got this error:

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.

This error is shown everytime I try to create a table, I tried `SELECT`, it works fine. I'm trying to understand what is wrong for hours, I only have one user, which I created when I setup the database for the first time, and I checked it's permission, it shows that I have permission to create a new table.

Also, everytime I connect to it with Management Studio 2016, it asks for me to add my IP, so I know that's not the issue.

I really have no idea how to continue from here, everything I found online people talk about granting permissions which it doesn't seems to be what is happening here, since I checked my permissions.

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says,`You don't have permission to create table in master database..try creating in your database`..

You can't create table in master database in SQLAzure.Master database in SQLAzure is readonly and is there, to hold information about roles,logins..

Check out this question as well:[Please explain SQL Azure "master" database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650357/please-explain-sql-azure-master-database)

Comment: thanks man, yes, I had no idea what was the 'master' database and apparently I was trying to create the table there, not on my existing database. That was happening because I was opening my SQL script on 'Recent Files', if I open it with File->Open, the script run on my db.