# Permission issue when using SymmetricDS with Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, symmetricds

I have two engines: postgres.properties (master node) and azure.properties. Both on the same machine. One database is local and one is in the cloud.

When SymmetricDS starts, it gives me this error for the azure engine:

```
2018-06-05 06:49:30,476 WARN [azure] [JdbcSqlTemplate] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'..  Failed to execute: CREATE TABLE "sym_channel"(
    "channel_id" VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    "processing_order" INT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    "max_batch_size" INT DEFAULT 1000 NOT NULL,
    "max_batch_to_send" INT DEFAULT 60 NOT NULL,
    "max_data_to_route" INT DEFAULT 100000 NOT NULL,
    "extract_period_millis" INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    "enabled" SMALLINT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    "use_old_data_to_route" SMALLINT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    "use_row_data_to_route" SMALLINT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    "use_pk_data_to_route" SMALLINT DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    "reload_flag" SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    "file_sync_flag" SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    "contains_big_lob" SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    "batch_algorithm" VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'default' NOT NULL,
    "data_loader_type" VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'default' NOT NULL,
    "description" VARCHAR(255),
    "queue" VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT 'default' NOT NULL,
    "max_network_kbps" DECIMAL(10,3) DEFAULT 0.000 NOT NULL,
    "data_event_action" CHAR(1),
    "create_time" DATETIME,
    "last_update_by" VARCHAR(50),
    "last_update_time" DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY ("channel_id")
)
```

This is because the 'master' database is [read-only in Azure SQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650357/please-explain-sql-azure-master-database). Right after that, the [azure] node shuts down.

> INFO [azure] [AbstractSymmetricEngine] [symmetric-engine-startup-1] Stopping SymmetricDS externalId=001 version=3.9.7 database=Microsoft SQL Server

.. and then the [postgres] node has this to say about it:

> WARN [postgres] [PushService] [postgres-push-default-3] Cannot push to node '001' in the group 'azure'.  The sync url is blank

The sync url and the registration url are set for both engines, so I assume the real issue is with the permission thing.

### **Question:**

**How do I fix this error?**
I assume I need to instruct SymmetricDS to use a database other than 'master', but how?

postgres.properties

```
engine.name=postgres
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver

# The JDBC URL used to connect to the database
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/<redacted>

# The user to login as who can create and update tables
db.user=<redacted>

# The password for the user to login as
db.password=<redacted>

registration.url=
sync.url=http://localhost:31415/sync/postgres-000

# Do not change these for running the demo
group.id=postgres
external.id=000

# Don't muddy the waters with purge logging
job.purge.period.time.ms=7200000

# This is how often the routing job will be run in milliseconds
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
# This is how often the push job will be run.
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
# This is how often the pull job will be run.
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
# Kick off initial load
initial.load.create.first=true
```

azure.properties

```
engine.name=azure
db.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver # located in the libs folder

# The JDBC URL used to connect to the database
db.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<redacted>

# The user to login as who can create and update tables
db.user=<redacted>

# The password for the user to login as
db.password=<redacted>

sync.url=http://localhost:31415/sync/azure-001
registration.url=http://localhost:31415/sync/postgres-000

group.id=azure
external.id=001

# This is how often the routing job will be run in milliseconds
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
# This is how often the push job will be run.
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
# This is how often the pull job will be run.
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file `azure.properties` the line with `sync.url` is commented out:

```
# sync.url=http://localhost:31415/sync/azure-001
```

The rule of thumb is that symmetricDs agent should be as close as possible to the database(s) it synchronises. There should be one symmetric-ds agent running close to the master node and another one in the cloud close to the azure instance. You wont be able to sync a read only database. SymmetricDs needs the write/read, even create table, function, package and trigger rights to work correctly

Comment: 1. This symmetric-ds instance is running in an Azure VM which is in the same datacenter as the SQL Server database. The PostgreSQL db is also running on that same VM. Everything is "as close as possible".
2. I un-commented the line (see updated post) but it still tells me the sync url is blank even I stop & restart symmetricDS
3. The goal is not to sync a read only database. It seems like SymmetricDS is trying to create all the
"sym_trigger", "sym_node", "sym_router", (etc.) tables in 'master', which is read-only. I assume what I need to do is to make it create those tables elsewhere.

Comment: You can create the sym_* tables, packages and true in another database schema

Comment: That's what I want to do, but how?
It tries to create these tables on its own, I didn't instruct it to do that. Where do I specify the database schema?

Comment: You can declare the schema in sym_trigger and other sym_* tables that configure the synchronization

Comment: Thanks! Turns out, on top of that, the jbdc URL provided by the Azure Portal wasn't formatted properly. After editing it, SymmetricDS no longer resorts to using the master db.

It's still telling me the sync url is blank for the "azure" node, though... Any idea?

Comment: Check if it really uses the properties file and not picking up some else...