# azure making an extra database when i create one

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

when i try to make an database online hosted on azure it will automatically create a second one

[image: before pressing showing hidden types]

[image: after pressing showing hidden types]

i've deleted the whole resource and try to make an database again i thought it was my mistake at first and i tried to make single database but still the same problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650357/please-explain-sql-azure-master-database

Comment: How are you creating this single database? Portal/CLI, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same and it only deploys the database which I created.

[image]

but the master database you are getting is a system database.

- All of a SQL Server system's system-level data is kept in the master database. This comprises metadata that is applicable to the entire instance, such as endpoints, related servers, and system configuration settings.
- As a result, if the master database is unavailable, SQL Server cannot start and you cannot delete it.

Refer this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/master-database?view=sql-server-ver16) for more information